# Chrome video playback, block video and allow audio only?

Tags: google-chrome

Especially when I am on laptop battery, I don't want to watch the video on a website (because it consumes a lot of resources and drains down battery) but only its audio.

Is it somehow possible to block the video content and only allow the audio content?

Comment: Don't think this is easily possible. Or at least it depends on the particular site you're targeting. The video will have to be downloaded and decoded in order to allow synchronization with the audio stream, so that'll cost CPU power. The only exception are transmissions where video and audio are sent in separate containers – then you could download the audio part only (e.g., on YouTube using `youtube-dl`).

Comment: @slhck that's what [Audio Only YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audio-only-youtube/pkocpiliahoaohbolmkelakpiphnllog?hl=en) is using?

Comment: I guess that's what it's doing, probably blocking video requests entirely by messing with the YouTube player's requests. What site are you targeting? (Otherwise I would define this question as too broad.)

Comment: I want to use this idea on all websites that have videos. When I am on laptop battery, I only want to listen to the audio to whatever video I am playing.